# JavaScript Prime Number

Tags: javascript, random, generator, primes

In JavaScript, how would I generate 100 random numbers and display the results of checking each one for primality, if I'm using a Boolean function named isPrime which then takes an integer as an argument and returns true if the argument is a prime number of false? For some reason I am stuck..

So far I have this:

```
function isPrime(number) {
    var start = 2;
    while (start <= Math.sqrt(number)) {
        if (number % start++ < 1) return false;
    }
    return number > 1;
}
```

Comment: What is your question actually?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random

Comment: https://www.google.com.br/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=prime%20numbers%20algorithm

Answer (score 1):

> how would I generate 100 random numbers

Use the `Math.random()` function. I assume you want random integers in some interval, so you can use a function like this:

```
function randomList(n, min, max) {
  var list = [];
  for(var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    list.push(Math.floor(min + Math.random() * (max - min)));
  }
  return list;
}
```

To generate, say, 100 random numbers between 0 and 250, you could call

```
randomList(100, 0, 250)
```

> and display the results of checking each one for primality

Loop through the random numbers you generated and use your `isPrime` function to check each one for primality:

```
var list = randomList(100, 0, 250);
for(var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
  var num = list[i];
  console.log(num + (isPrime(num) ? " is prime." : " is not prime."));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you want to generate a random number use:

```
 Math.random();
```

this only gives you a number like 0.8656630991026759
now what is the limit of your random number?
0 to 100 or some other limits so you can simply multiply this number with higher limit.

for example 
Math.random()*100 should give me a random number from 0 to 100.

now check if the number is prime. Here are two examples of isprime:

```
// This version has the fewest lines of code - but is very slow.
// It checks if n is dividible by every integer 2, 3, 4, 5 ... 
// up to sqrt(n)

function isPrime1(n) {
 if (isNaN(n) || !isFinite(n) || n%1 || n<2) return false; 
 var m=Math.sqrt(n);
 for (var i=2;i<=m;i++) if (n%i==0) return false;
 return true;
}

// The next version is better: it checks the divisor 2 separately;
// then, it proceeds to check odd divisors only, from 3 up to sqrt(n).
// At most half of the numbers between 3 and sqrt(n) are checked.

function isPrime2(n) {
 if (isNaN(n) || !isFinite(n) || n%1 || n<2) return false; 
 if (n%2==0) return (n==2);
 var m=Math.sqrt(n);
 for (var i=3;i<=m;i+=2) {
  if (n%i==0) return false;
 }
 return true;
}
```

check this link for more info on isprime function
source : http://www.javascripter.net/faq/numberisprime.htm